# Search all elements on multiple lists

Tags: c#

I want to **compare if the actual position of the drone is in any of the lists**.
Look at the comment. I dont know how to search if that actual position is in any of the elements of all the lists created (k lists).

actual_position is a point.

```
 private void function()
    {
        int distance = 2;

        for (int k = 0; k < drone.Length; k++)
        {
                //create a list of each drone and add the actual position
                list[k].Add(actual_position);
                //create multiple  positions ( something like a safe area around actual_position based on distance
                for (int i = (int)actual_position.X - distance; i <= (int)actual_position.X + distance; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = (int)actual_position.Y - distance; j <= (int)actual_position.Y + distance; j++)
                    {
                        //add position to the list
                        list[k].Add(new PointF(i, j));
                    }

                }

               //if actual_position of a different drone == any element of list (all the lists k)


        }

    }
```

**Edit:**

Basically I'm putting the drone's position and a safe area around it. For example I dont want any of the other drones to go in that safe area. basically if actual_position == any element of list (all the lists k) stop moving.

Comment: I don't see any of these lists... A naïve approach would be to do pointsLists.SelectMany(p => p).Contains(actual_position). If you could do a distance based search you would be better off though.

Comment: what do you mean u dont see any of this lists? list is a array of lists of points.

Comment: Ok, that's not clear since the declaration isn't included in the post

Comment: `list` is indeed an array, not a `List<T>`.  Furthermore, you didn't show where you declared or assigned that variable.

Comment: check my edit please.

Comment: `System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(list, x=>x.Equals(actual_position))`returns `true` if `actual_position` has equivalent coordinates to any point in `list`. This works because [`PointF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf(v=vs.110).aspx) implements `Equals` to compare coordinates.

Comment: @Quantic are you sure it's only list? I dont need to put list[k]? it will search is all lists created? Because list[k] is an array of lists. basically it's one list of each drone.

Comment: Sorry I missed that despite you making a point of this being a list of lists. You can use LINQ's [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) to flatten a list of lists into a single list; here I replaced `list` with the `SelectMany` call: `System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(list, x=>x), x=>x.Equals(actual_position))`

Comment: Given a sufficiently large set SelectMany will cause a rather large enumeration however, you would typically use some kind of octree to pair the results down first. (hence my note that its a naïve solution above)